# C++ Cauer/elliptic filter starting point

Tags: c++, filtering

I am learning C++ and, with my current knowledge, I thought I could make a Cauer filter since all there is needed is the math. My problem is that I don't have a starting point. Should I choose switch/case? If/else? It's a bit complicated.

Overall, the filter is a function of 5 parameters, Ap, As, fp, fs, and N (no need for details), and for any 4 of these 5, the 5th comes out automatically. So, for example, if Ap is specified, then there is an intermediary term, epsilonP = sqrt(10^(Ap/10)-1), but if Ap=0 (needed to be deduced out of the other 4), then it's a function of As and nomeQ, which nomeQ is, indirectly, a ratio of fp and fs. And, to make it worse, all of these, epsilonP, nomeQ, etc, are needed for the final calculations.

Initially, I tried to use if/else, here's what I have:

```
double epsilonP, epsilonS, epsilonSC;
if (Ap)
    epsilonP = sqrt(pow(10, Ap/10) - 1);
else
    epsilonP = 16 * (pow(10, As/10) - 1) * exp(log(nomeQ) * N);
```

But nomeQ is a function of h0 (in this case), which is a function of modulusK, which is a function of the ration of fp and fs (or fs/fp, depending on another parameter, filterType), which are the initial terms that can be specified to be null so that they can be automatically determined from the other 4! As is similar: f(As) if As>0, else f(nomeQ), nomeQ can either be f(h0) as above, or a direct function of N. modulusK is either f(fp,fs) as above, or depending on nomeQ2, which is a function of N and nomeQ1... I hope you see my problem.

Just so you don't get the wrong ideas, the filter is implemented in LTspice and working (see ltspicegoodies.ltwiki.org/files/Filter.7z, or .zip -- search for "subckt Cauer" inside filter.sub), but not with every possibility since LTspice can only do so much (only N, Ap or As can be null). Which is why I started learning C++, but... here I am.

So, my problem: can anyone suggest a starting point for all this? I don't mean someone making this for me, just asking for an advice on how to tackle the labyrinth. And I'm not talking about a program for each possibility, that's not a solution. I started writing it but when I got to epsilonP and I realized the complications, I simply shut down, out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with switch/case, something like this:

```
input fp, fs, Ap, As, N;
int test {(fp > 0) + 2*(fs > 0) + 3*(Ap > 0) + 4*(As > 0) + 5*(N > 0)};
switch (test)
{
  case 14: nomeQ, modulusK, ...
  case 13: nomeQ, modulusK, ...
  case 12:
  case 11:
  default:
  case 10:
}
rest of the code;
```

What I didn't know for sure was if the case wouldn't complain about, for example, division by zero in the non-true branches. Apparently, even if the true branch has a division by zero as a result of calculations, it will compile, but it will crash when run. For false branches it happily runs ignoring them.

So far, this seems the best solution, but my question remains: if someone with more experience has encountered something like this, I'd appreciate a hint or a nudge in the right direction for a better solution (this can't be the only one). I am only just learning C++.